# Add additional buttons to Autocomplete

Tags: material-ui

I would like to know if its possible to add an additional button next to the cross, and down arrow on the Autocomplete, but still leave the current buttons intack.
I tried using endAdorement on the text field, and it removed the existing buttons.
I think there is probably some correct way to do this, but still not seeing it.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Cheers
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Have worked out how to go forward with this, incase anyone else has the same issue, use the useAutocomplete hook, and then render it however you want too.